# How do I resolve these errors for SLURM?

Tags: bash, slurm

```
#SBATCH -J myjob                        # Job name
#SBATCH -o myjob.o%j                    # Name of stdout output file (%j corresponds to the job id)
#SBATCH -e myjob.e%j                    # Name of stderr error file (%j corresponds to the job id)
#SBATCH -p gpu-a100                   # Queue (partition) name
#SBATCH -N 1                            # Total # of nodes (must be 1 for serial)
#SBATCH -n 64                           # Number of cores
#SBATCH -t 24:00:00                     # Run time (hh:mm:ss)
#SBATCH --mail-user=kunjal.shah@utexas.edu
#SBATCH --mail-type=all                 # Send email at begin and end of job (can assign begin or end as well)
#SBATCH -A CCR23005         # Allocation name (req'd if you have more than 1)

# Other commands must follow all #SBATCH directives...

cdw
python TypeT5/train_model.py
```

Here is my file `commands.slurm` . After doing `sbatch commands.slurm`, I am getting the error: Pushover: (Failed: Training spot model.) You set `--ntasks=64` in your SLURM bash script, but this variable is not supported. HINT: Use `--ntasks-per-node=64

However, I have not used --ntasks=64 anywhere. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: This does not look like a SLURM error. I think that you will have to research on the documentation of the tool you are executing.
In any case, you are wrong, you used the `--ntasks` option and you set it to 64 explicitly in your SLURM script.

Comment: You've used it here. `#SBATCH -n 64` . `-n` and `--ntasks` are the same. Just type `sbatch --help` to see all the available options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have used the `--ntasks` but in a different way.

See below from the sbatch documentation:

> -n, --ntasks=
> sbatch does not launch tasks, it requests an allocation of resources and submits a batch script. This option advises the Slurm
> controller that job steps run within the allocation will launch a
> maximum of number tasks and to provide for sufficient resources.

Instead of `#SBATCH --ntasks=64` in the script you have used `#SBATCH -n 64`. Hence the error, so it is not somehow not supported in your environment. Please consider using the alternatives to avoid this particular error.